# Delete Entire Rows Based on Col N Criteria

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

I am unable to figure out why the following code will not delete the entire row if the cell in Col `N` has the word `"Completed"`.

```
Sub DeleteRowBasedOnCriteria()    
Dim RowToTest As Long    

For RowToTest = Cells(Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1    

With Cells(RowToTest, 14)    
    If .Value <> "Completed" _    
    Then _    
    Rows(RowToTest).EntireRow.Delete    
End With    

Next RowToTest    

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it work with the following code:

Sub DeleteRowBasedOnCriteria2()
  Sheets("InProcess").Select

```
  Dim RowToTest As Long  

  For RowToTest = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1  
      With ActiveSheet.Cells(RowToTest, 14)  
          If .Value = "Completed" Then ActiveSheet.Rows(RowToTest).EntireRow.Delete   
    End With  
  Next RowToTest
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1):

Problems with the continuations:

```
Sub DeleteRowBasedOnCriteria()
    Dim RowToTest As Long

    For RowToTest = Cells(Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        With Cells(RowToTest, 14)
            If .Value <> "Completed" Then Rows(RowToTest).EntireRow.Delete
        End With
    Next RowToTest

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried your suggestion, and for some reason nothing is getting deleted. Most of the rows are blank; only a few have "Completed" in Col N. So most rows should delete.

Comment: @KimG Is the sheet with the data ***Active*** when the macro is run ??

Comment: Yes it sure it. It looks like the code stops after "Then" and skips the deletion part.

Comment: Your original code worked for me also.  Have you tried running the code without actually deleting.  For example, coloring the row or adding a value next to column N?  If the the macro correctly identifies all rows as you expect then the issue is with the delete statement.  Can you delete rows manually?

Comment: I just realized that it's going back to a different worksheet (Sheet1) and deleting each and every row one at a time. Any clues? What am I missing?

Comment: @KimG  It's not going back to Sheet1...Sheet1 is ***Active*** when the macro is running.........make sure the proper sheet is ***Active*** **before** you run the macro !

Comment: It's deleting every single row regardless if completed or not. Here's my code:    
    Sub DeleteRowBasedOnCriteria()  
    Sheets("Completed").Select  

        Dim RowToTest As Long  

        For RowToTest = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step   -1
            With Cells(RowToTest, 14)  
            If .Value <> "Completed" Then Rows(RowToTest).EntireRow.Delete  
            End With  
        Next RowToTest  

    End Sub
(Sorry it's not formatting)

Comment: Is there any other way to activate this spreadsheet other than:
    Sheets("Completed").Select       or    

    Worksheets("Completed").Activate.

Comment: @KimG ......................No...................., *but you could always use With* ....................

Comment: I'm going to assume that another procedure is impacting this one. Thanks for your help!.

Answer (score 0):

That suggestion is minimalistic but...

Sub DeleteRowBasedOnCriteria()
Dim RowToTest As Long

For RowToTest = Cells(Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1

With Cells(RowToTest, 14)
    If .Value <> "Completed" _
    Then _
    **.EntireRow.Delete**
End With

Next RowToTest

End Sub

Comment: This is so odd. When I step through the program, it literally skips over the line .EntireRow.Delete for the entire run (not just when it doesn't apply), just as it did the other program. I'm completely stumped on this one. Any other ideas at all?

Comment: That's because you used the _ instead of If .Value <> "Completed" Then //
.EntireRow.Delete// end if  But the line is deleted, right?  If not, break point, check if the value is "Completed". Case sensitive.